# LTC3873-5 doesn´t work

Tags: dc-dc-converter

**Update**: I found the solution...
There is a wrong resistor assembled in the `VFB` circuit. `R12` is unequal to `108k`.

---

I have this power supply circuit to drive an application over a battery:

[image]

The circuit is taken from the official [device datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/38735fb.pdf) but it seems that the DC/DC converter isn´t running. I power the circuits DC/DC LT3873-5 with 5 V and I measure a 5 V input voltage for the `L4931` hence the 12 V rail.

The layout looks like this:

[image]
[image]

And I measure the following voltages:

- Pin 1 (IPRG): 0 V
- Pin 2 (ITH): 0.53 V
- Pin 3 (VFB): 2.7 V
- Pin 5 (NGATE): 0 V
- Pin 7 (RUN): 3.8 V
- Pin 8 (SW): 4.7 V

So what is wrong here?

Comment: It appears that the chip is not driving the MOSFET. The cause could be a bad chip, a bad MOSFET, or even a bad layout. First, check all the connections and voltages around the controller chip. Post your layout and setup if you still can't resolve.

Comment: Hello,
I found the solution :)

Comment: Since the voltage in your VFB is different from 1V thats mean your  voltage divider does not use the correct resistance values